# How to find tax accountant to advise on double taxation for US citizen working in UK for US company

Tags: taxes

I am looking for a tax accountant in either the US or UK who would be willing to consult with me about the following situation:

> A US citizen will be moving to the UK on a Tier 2 (spousal) visa for one year (that does not overlap with the tax year in either country). She will work from home in the UK, for a US company that will pay into her US bank. What are our tax liabilities in both countries?

Having spoken to the UK HMRC, it seems that the UK's answer will depend on the US's answer, which in turns depends on the UK's answer.

I'm not looking for advice about the question above, just specifically whether or not there exists a tax accountant (or some other service) that I can consult with who could advise me on the tax situation in both countries at once. I could not find anyone via Google. Do such people exist?

Comment: Have you googled "US expats tax UK"?

Comment: I have had to file simultaneous returns in the UK, the US, and a 3rd country.  And yes, there are some great tax accountants out there.  I don't think it's in the rules to promote a particular tax person, but indeed yes, there are SEVERAL good ones.

Comment: @littleadv, thanks that phrase was more useful than what I had googled before.

Comment: @GayotFow, thanks for your comment, could you describe how you found your tax accountant?

Comment: I asked on [UKY](http://talk.uk-yankee.com/index.php?board=11.0) and got one for a while, then when I started my own company I got a different one.  I was delinquent in FBAR so needed to upgrade.  The tax guy also did my 3rd country which was above expectations as I was planning to go delinquent on that one.